# options when it comes to multi user apps

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a plan for a an app that allows multiple users, who'll know each other and select each other for interaction, to go head to head in a football score game. There is no suggestions in my book for this kind of project and I've googled but can't come across information. 
What options are available to allow specific people to share data (each person will have the app installed)? 
My thoughts lead to a database table of users that would let them 'friend' each other and a table of scores referenced to each person which could be called and presented. Are there other ways? Thanks

Comment: That's a very broad question. One could probably write multiple books about that. Such questions aren't very good for stackoverflow. -- For now you might want to look at parse.com or CloudKit (made by Apple, built into iOS8). If you search for these in your favorite search engine, you should find lots of tutorials and information.

Comment: I understand that it's broad but I have no other place to ask. Am I right though in thinking, in order for two people to interact, they will need to find each other / friend each other first via a database search?